# How to access the odoo runbot builds

Tags: nginx, odoo, reverse-proxy, odoo-8

I'm have installed odoo runbot and build is working fine. But I try to access the build it doesn't work. See below.

**This site can’t be reached xxx-master-xx.runbot.abc.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. Here is my nginx conf.

```
   #odoo server
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}
upstream runbot_instances {
 server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=200m;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name runbot.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        send_timeout 200m;
        proxy_read_timeout 200m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 200m;
        proxy_pass    http://runbot;
    }
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name ~^(.*)\.runbot\.example\.com$;
 #server_name *.runbot.example.com;
 location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   send_timeout 200m;
   proxy_read_timeout 200m;
   proxy_connect_timeout 200m;
   proxy_pass    http://runbot_instances;
  }
}


server {
 listen 443;
 server_name *.runbot.example.com;
 proxy_read_timeout 720s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
 proxy_send_timeout 720s;

 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; includeSubdomains";
 proxy_set_header X-Odoo-dbfilter %h;

 # SSL parameters
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/runbot.example.com/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/runbot.example.com/privkey.pem;
 ssl_session_timeout 30m;

 # log
 access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

 # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
 location /longpolling {
 proxy_pass http://odoochat;
 }

 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://odoo;
 }

 # common gzip
 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
 gzip on;
}
```

Please let me know how can I fix this. I tried official documentation but I can't solve this issue.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to add the nginx config to get an answer or even better the correct answer. With so less information it is just very difficult to think about all possibilities.

Comment: @CZoellner I have added my nginx conf. May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
proxy_pass    http://runbot;
```

For:

```
proxy_pass    http://odoo;
```

Everything else seems fine.